# ConcurrentQueue with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrent-queue

I am new to multi threading concepts. I need to add certain number of strings to a queue and process them with multiple threads. Using `ConcurrentQueue` which is thread safe.

This is what I have tried. But all the items added into concurrent queue are not processed. only first 4 items are processed.

```
class Program
{
    ConcurrentQueue<string> iQ = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().run();
    }

    void run()
    {
        int threadCount = 4;
        Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            int workerId = i;
            Task task = new Task(() => worker(workerId));
            workers[i] = task;
            task.Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            iQ.Enqueue("Item" + i);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(workers);
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void worker(int workerId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);
        string op;
        if(iQ.TryDequeue(out op))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
    }


}
```

Comment: if you change the threadCount to a different number. does it work any differently?

Comment: When you start a worker, the queue is empty.

Comment: That functionality is *already* provided by the [ActionBlock<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: PS creating cold tasks and calling `Start` is a serious bug. You *never* need to do that. Just use `Task.Run(somemethod)` to run your job. Tasks aren't threads either. You can *schedule* a class for execution but the framework decides when and how to run it. Creating 4 tasks doesn't mean you get 4 threads

Comment: If you are new to multithreading concepts, I would not start with a concurrent queue. You need them mainly for lock-free multithreading, which is an advanced concept. You should start working with locks and when you are comfortable there, move forward to lock-free multithreading.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi, I am not clear about task are not threads, how can I create threads and is thread more efficient than task?

Comment: Don't. Use an `ActionBlock<T>`, it *already* does what you ask. It has a concurrent queue input, you can specify that it uses 1 or more workers, you can specify a *limit* to the input to enforce throttling. You can also combine it with other blocks from the TPL Dataflow library to create pipelines of processing blocks, similar to a Powershell pipeline

Comment: What you probably need is a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) instead of a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your implementation. The first and obvious one is that the `worker` method only dequeues zero or one item and then stops:

```
    if(iQ.TryDequeue(out op))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
    }
```

It should be:

```
    while(iQ.TryDequeue(out op))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
    }
```

That however won't be enough to make your program work properly. If your workers are dequeueing faster than the main thread is enqueueing, they will stop while the main task is still enqueueing. You need to signal the workers that they can stop. You can define a boolean variable that will be set to `true` once enqueueing is done:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    iQ.Enqueue("Item" + i);
}
Volatile.Write(ref doneEnqueueing, true);
```

The workers will check the value:

```
void worker(int workerId)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);
    do {
        string op;
        while(iQ.TryDequeue(out op))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
        }
        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Volatile.Read(ref doneEnqueueing) || (iQ.Count > 0));
    }
    while (!Volatile.Read(ref doneEnqueueing) || (iQ.Count > 0))
    Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
}
```

Comment: Hi, one query, will this signalling stops the threads to wait until enqueueing is  completed ?

Comment: @Naveenkumar The signal will stop them from _finishing_ until enqueueing is completed _and_ the queue is empty. The workers will already start while the enqueueing is going on.

Comment: Thanks , you have given me right direction to work :)

Comment: hi, need one help, how can I start my workers only after at least one item is added into queue?

Comment: @Naveenkumar: By enqueueing first and then starting the tasks. Your code does it in the opposit order.

Comment: by enqueueing first and starting tasks, as enqueueing is happening in for loop, tasks will start after all items are enqueued into queue, how is it a good option?

Comment: @Naveenkumar: The current solution enqueues after the tasks are started and the tasks can handle it. That solution works well if enqueueing can last a long time. If you enqueue first and then start the tasks you could just as well distribute your data equally to four different lists (one for each task) and then let each of them handle their list. You have absolutely no synchronization effort then and your solution is much easier. It all depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Your  workers take one item out of the `queue` and then finish the work, just let them work till `queue` is empty.

Replace `if` in worker function with `while`

```
void worker(int workerId)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);
    string op;
    while (iQ.TryDequeue(out op))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
}
```

As you will run it you will see, that near all items will be processed by two workers. Reason: your cpu has two cores, both are working and there is no "free tiem slot" to create new task. If you want to have all your 4 task to process items, you could add a delay to give your processor time to create anotehr tasks, something like:

```
while (iQ.TryDequeue(out op))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).Wait();
}
```

that gives you output, that you want:

```
...
Worker 0 is processing item Item8
Worker 1 is processing item Item9
Worker 2 is processing item Item10
Worker 3 is processing item Item11
Worker 3 is processing item Item13
Worker 1 is processing item Item12
...
```

Comment: worker 2 and 3 do not process anything. how many items should each worker process?

Comment: they have no free time to start, other tasks are working, not waiting, to simulate this you could add wait after processing an item:   Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, op);
  Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).Wait();

Comment: @waynemodz there should not be any restriction on number of items to be processed by each worker, if an item is added into queue, if any thread is free, it should process the item.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin Hi, thanks for the response, your suggestion is working :)

Comment: @Naveenkumar than you are allowed to give an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been working with `ConcurrentQueue` quite a bit recently and thought I'd share this.  I've create a custom `ConcurrentQueue` called `CQItems` that has methods to build itself with given parameters.  Internally, when you tell it to build *x* number of *y* items, it makes a `Parallel.For` call to the item constructors.  The benefit here is that when a method or function calls `CQItems myCQ = CQItems.Generate(x, y)` that call comes from the base application thread, meaning that nothing can look at the queue until it is finished building. But internally to the queue class, it's building with threads, and is significantly quicker than just using a `List<>` or `Queue<>`.  Mostly it's generating things out of thin air, but it also sometimes (based on params) is creating items from SQL - basically generating objects based on existing data.  At any rate, these are the two methods in the `CQItems` class that can help with this:

```
public void Generate(int numberOfItems = 1, ItemOptions options = ItemOptions.NONE)
    {
        try
        {
            Type t = typeof(T);

            if (t == typeof(Item))
                throw new ArgumentException("Type " + t + " is not valid for generation.  Please contact QA.");

            else
                Parallel.For(0, numberOfItems, (i, loopState) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        GenerateItemByType(typeof(T), options);
                    }

                    catch
                    {
                        loopState.Stop();
                        throw;
                    }

                });
        }

        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((x) =>
            {
                if (x is SQLNullResultsException)
                {
                    throw x;
                }
                else if (x is ImageNotTIFFException)
                {
                    throw x;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw x;
                }

                return true;
            });
        }

        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            ItemManager.Instance.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateItemByType(Type t, ItemOptions options = ItemOptions.NONE)
    {
        try
        {
            if (t == typeof(ItemA))
            {
                if ((options & ItemOptions.DUPLICATE) != 0)
                {
                    this.Enqueue(new ItemB(options));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Enqueue(new ItemA(options));
                }
            }
            else if (t == typeof(ItemC))
            {
                this.Enqueue(new ItemC(options));
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally { }
    }
```

Some useful notes:

Supplying the `loopState` variable in the `Parallel.For()` allows us to set the state to *stop* if an exception is caught.  This is nice because if your loop is asked to do 1000 things, and the 5th iteration throws an exception, it's going to keep looping.  You may want it to, but in my case an exception needs to exit the threaded loop.  You'll still end up with an `AggregateException` coming out of it (apparently, that's just what happens when threads throw exception).  Parsing those out and only sending the first one can save a LOT of time and headaches trying to weed through a giant exception group where later exceptions may (or may not) have been caused due to the first anyway.

As for the rethrows, I try to add a catch statement for most expected types of exceptions even if I plan to just throw them up the stack anyway.  Part of this is for troubleshooting (being able to break on specific exceptions can be handy).  Part of it is because sometimes I want to be able to do other things, such as stopping the loop, changing or adding to the exception message, or in the case of breaking apart the `AggregateException`, only send one exception back up the stack rather than the whole aggregate.  Just a point of clarification for anyone who might be looking at this.

Lastly, in case it's confusing, the `Type(T)` value is coming from my `CQItems` class itself:

```
     public class CQItems<T> : ConcurrentQueue<Item>, IDisposable
```